# Is it possible to rename characters in Castle Crashers?

Tags: ps3, castle-crashers

Is it possible to rename characters in Castle Crashers? All created characters are named "profile name(number)" and are hard to distinguish.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, [you can rename characters in Castle Crashers local play by renaming your PSN local profile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMo-ZVJJxOg), but No, you can't resolve the core problem of your issue.** Castle crashers still uses the same naming system and even by changing profile names, All your characters will still be named *Profile Name (#)* and be just as hard to distinguish.